# Philips PE1535 bench power supply - reason for design choice?

Tags: power-supply, negative-voltage

Just a little question about the Philips power supply PE1535.

Link to original manual :
http://bee.mif.pg.gda.pl/ciasteczkowypotwor/Philips/PE1535%20-%20PE1545.pdf

Why the negative power supply realized with VZ113, V114 and V115 that produce -10v are connected to the positive output X2?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they just want to ensure the output can go down to 0V so they sink a bit of current from the output via R134.

This will take care of any leakage in the Sziklai output stage, and will discharge C104 reasonably promptly when you crank the output voltage down.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr Spehro, 
so if I understand correctly :
1- This negative power supply acts as a load at the output of the power supply, but what is the limit of this method?
2- What are the advantages and disadvantages of this method?